# parallel requests from frontend to server in javascript(React.js)

Tags: node.js, reactjs

in my app I am requesting the server from multiple places on the same page to different API
in this approach I am just randomly calling API and not able to figure whether its causing problems or not , would it cause any problem to my response coming from different API

Comment: It's quite difficult to understand your question. Many web applications make multiple, parallel requests to many servers, and they don't have problems. It could cause problems if the code is not set up to handle those requests correctly, but with such a broad question, it's hard to say "yes" or "no".

Comment: @heretic Monkey thanks for your feedback, in simple words while making request to a api and immediately I make request to next api will the call be overridden by the recent call